# Average of the last 7 entries only using AverageIF in Excel

Tags: excel

```
 =AVERAGEIF(Stats!C:C,B2,Stats!B:B)
```

Can someone please help me. This is my formula to get the averageIF to get the value for B2. I add entries daily. I get the value for everything, but I need to get the average for only the last 7 entries of B2 every time I add something.

stats

```
  | Date      | Rank | Player |   |   |
|-----------|------|--------|---|---|
| 28-Oct-16 | 3    | KD     |   |   |
| 28-Oct-16 | 4    | T.J.   |   |   |
| 28-Oct-16 | 5    | TB     |   |   |
```

Sheet2

```
| Rank | Player |   |   |   |
|------|--------|---|---|---|
| 1    | KD     |   |   |   |
| 2    | T.J.   |   |   |   |
| 5    | DG     |   |   |   |
```

The value in B2 is a constant.  I have the avg of all the entries of B:B with my averageif statement,  but  I also want the avg of the last 7 occurences of B2 in Stats1 when I add to it. I do not want to use the date because the player will not appear in Column C everyday. Thank you

Comment: Please mock up some data to show what determines the last 7.  Do you have a time stamp per entry?  Are the entries in order so the newest is always added to the bottom?

Comment: Are all the values in B2? Like today B2 will be `1,2,3,4,5,6,7` and then tomorrow, it'll be `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`? If so, how are the values delimited, with a space? Comma? As @ScottCraner asks, some sample data would help.

Comment: Sorry it's my first time I post here. It would be clearer if I  could add a screenshot

Comment: add the data to the original post and not the comments.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables to generate tables in text, then paste into your question as code. (Paste in, select, press Ctrl-K to indent each row by 4 spaces.) This is apparently the best way to put table data into StackExchange. You mention `Sheet 1`, `Sheet 2` in your comment, but the formula has a sheet named `Stats`?

Comment: Thanks Jack! I was able to fix it. sheet 1 = stats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to use either an array formula using `INDEX`, `MATCH`, `COUNT`, and some other functions or a helper column to identify the last 7 records for each player.

I will be demonstrating the helper column, as it is easier to implement and most likely faster.

On stats, in a new column, you're going to want to use the following formula `=COUNTIF(C:C,C2)-COUNTIF($C$1:C2,C2)+1`. Place that in row 2 of your helper column and extend it for all records. This formula counts the number of records for the player in that row, and subtracts the number of occurrences at or before that row. You will get ascending counts for each player.

Next, in "Sheet 2", you can use the formula `=AVERAGEIFS(Stats!B:B,Stats!C:C,B2,Stats!D:D,"<=7")` to take the average of all records with the player in B2 where the helper column (D) has a value less that 7. I placed the formula in A2 and dragged it down for each player.

Comment: It worked! I spend hours trying to figure it out yesterday. Thank you so much Fritz!